# dismissViewControllerAnimated not animating ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I want to **slide in** a ViewController in the screen, and then at some point **slide it out** and go back to the presenting ViewController.
I use this code from my MainViewController to launch the modal, and then to dismiss it.

Why is the dismiss slide **animation**  **not working?**

```
// Present a React Component sliding from the right on top of current ViewController
+ (void)presentSlidingFromRight:(UIViewController*)presented onViewController:(UIViewController*)presenterVC {
    CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
    transition.duration = 1;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [presenterVC.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [presenterVC presentViewController:presented animated:NO completion:nil];
}

// Dismiss a React Component sliding to the right
+ (void)dismissSlidingToRight:(UIViewController*)presented onViewController:(UIViewController*)presenterVC {
    CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
    transition.duration = 3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [presenterVC.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [presenterVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try changing this line:

```
[presenterVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

for this one:

```
[presenterVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

**Update**

Make sure you are calling your static functions on the `Main Thread`

Comment: When i set it to YES, the modal animates but with default animation (sliding to bottom fast). Why is it ignoring my Transition?

Comment: @Herno in the dismiss function, could you try changing the transition type, use fade instead of push:

`transition.type = kCATransitionFade;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. So if i run the code in my MainView Controller, it works well. But as i have this static class, i don't know why it does not animate.  I am keeping the _presented and presenting controllers in varaibles for later use.  It's the same code, but it does not work when i use it in another class that is not MainViewController. How weird is that?

Comment: Maybe you are not calling them on the `Main Thread`, Can you show me how are you calling these static functions?

Comment: Yes i just found out!  i need to include dispatch_async to make it work!. Can you edit the answer and i will accept it! Thanks!